# Create a function given expected behavior, domain and values of constants

Tags: functions

I a trying to create a mathematical function in R that:

1. has parameters $a,b$ and $c$, all real and positive numbers, if possible within the range of $(20,60)$.
2. $f(a)=\infty$
3. $f(b)=$ inflexion point
4. $f(c)= 0$

I would like that the function resembles an exponential function but where I can manipulate these three points $a$, $b$ and $c$ to my will?

Is it possible to do that? Which would be the way to find it?
Here is some Rcode to play with:

```
a=36,
b=42,
c=47
x=seq(a,c, by=0.1)
y=vector()
for (i in 1:length(x)){ y[i] =1/(a*(1-exp(-b*x[i])-c))};y
plot(y~x)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one:

$$f(x)=\frac{c-x}{(a-x)(1+e^{b-x})}$$

I've plotted it below, with $c=1,a=2,b=3$:

[image]

And another plot, with $b=6$, so that you can better see the inflection point:

[image]

Comment: thanks, but it does not conform the characteristics that i asked for: it does not go to zero in c nor infinite in a.                                                               stime=vector()#survival time
t=seq(from=40, to=47,by=0.1)a=36
b=42
c=47  
i=1
for (i in 1:length(t)){ stime[i] =(c−t[i])/((a−t[i])*(1+exp(b−t[i])))};stime
plot(stime~t)

Comment: Look at the formula I posted: What is $f$ if $x=c$? Well, then it says $c-c$ in the numerator, so $f(c)=0$. Now let's look at $x=a$. Then it says $a-a$ in the *denominator*, and if the denominator is zero, $f$ is infinite.

Comment: Actually yes, there was a problem in r because I added a parenthesis grouping the two binomials of the denominator. Now, adding to your formula a minus symbol the output for x=a is inf, which is what i need. However, it seems i cant manipulate the knee of the curve using b. I need to manipulate it so i can make it to vary between 35 and 45.

Comment: For each value of b i got that it corresponds to a different part of the region of inflexion of the curve. higher values are closer to the end of the curve's inflexion. The opposite happens with smaller values.

Comment: The inflection point is the point where the function goes from being convex to being concave, i.e. $f''(x)=0$. This happens for $f(b)$, which is exactly what you asked for.

Comment: Thanks heaps for all this help, Lovsovs. Maybe in my ignorance, the point i need is actually the "knee of the curve" instead of the inflexion point? I know that this knee depends on the y axis (http://www.growth-dynamics.com/articles/Kurzweil.htm) so i am not sure if i need one or the other point. Thinking it twice, in practice i need that at b the curve always takes values below 8. Could it be possible that the inflexion point (or the knee of the curve) is always below 8? Thanks again for your amazing help.

Comment: @Aguscamacho No problem, happy to help! If you want to, you can upvote and/or "accept" my answer (the latter is the little tick under the up/down-vote arrows).
You can force the curve around the $b$-part to always stay under a certain value (e.g. $8$) by multiplying it in the numerator, like so: $$f(x)=\frac{(c-x) \cdot 8}{(a-x)(1+e^{b-x})}$$ Try playing around with the values yourself to see which parameter does what.

Comment: Infinite thankful!

Comment: I have been dealing with the curve for a long time now and it seems necessary that i give it a big, real value when x=a, instead of infinite. Would you please advice me how?

Comment: I don't have an idea for a analytical expression right off the bat, but if you're using this in a programming context, you could probably define the function so as to return the big number whenever the function I gave returns infinite, simply by adding a conditional.

Comment: thanks for all your help. After I have been struggling with this curve for a long time i wonder if you would like to help taking it to its final form, you could be co-author of an article on thermal vulnerability of animals. Probably, you deserve that already. If you are interested, you may mail me at my user name, in gmail.

Comment: @Aguscamacho That is very generous of you, but I will decline. Please use my answer as you please (without needing to credit me in any publication). Cheers.

Comment: Many thanks anyway, Lovsovs.